# Correct way to use multiple possessive apostrophes in sentences?

Tags: punctuation, possessives, apostrophe

I find multiple possessive apostrophes confusing, and so I'm having trouble deciding which of the sentences below would be correct.

Example:

- The bicycle's frame colour is red.
- The bicycle frame's colour is red.
- The bicycle's frame's colour is red.

Another example:

- The thief's stash jewelry is very valuable.
- The thief stash's jewelry is very valuable.
- The thief's stash's jewelry is very valuable.

What would be the correct way to use apostrophes in these sentences?

Many thanks for helping.

Comment: The bicycle frame's colour is red. The thief's jewelry stash is very valuable.

Comment: It's not very good English to express it in that way. Most people would say 'The bicycle's frame is red' or, if you must mention the word _colour_, 'The colour of the bicycle frame is red.' 'The thief's stash of jewellery is very valuable.'

Comment: 'Bicycle frame' is a compound, so _The bicycle frame's colour is red_. // With a better example, _The thief's mask's colour was green._  No compounding, no collocation, merely free association: so _A's B's C_. Compare _His mask's colour_.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, that makes a lot more sense now. English language has never been a very strong subject of mine as you can probably tell. I was asking because I noticed on a wiki "_Courier's Stash's_ Classic Pack"  which doesn't sound right, although it's a bit more complicated as _Courier's Stash_ is the name of something so the apostrophe must be in it's name.

Comment: You can 'chain' possessive apostrophes - the man's uncle's dog's tail's tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning the first example, as "bicycle" and "frame" are inanimates that do not seem to be part of those inanimates for which the Saxon genitive can be used exceptionally I wouldn't use these constructions but only "**the colour of the bicycle frame**" ("[bicycle frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_frame)" being an established compound noun).

In the case of the second,  as "thief" is the noun for naming a human being I'd use either "**the thief's stashed jewelry**" or "**the jewelry in the thief's stash**".

Comment: Your reasoning seems to indicate that you'd consider "The bicycle frame's colour is red." improper. The reason "thief's stash's jewelry" sounds odd is that "the jewelry in the thief's stash" is far more reasonable than "the jewelry of the thief's stash"; "the colour of the bicycle frame" is fine, showing a more acceptable instancing of the  proprietorial metaphor.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, this construction is still being taught as proper only for human beings, animals and firms, institutions, geographical places and time expressions but not usually for lifeless material things (https://anglais-pratique.fr/index.php/rubriques/fondements/55-cas-possessif-genitif); it seems there has been much erosion of that principle and that maybe the teaching directives  are note quite in step any more.

Comment: CGEL gives, for instance, _the sun's rays, the room's Persian carpet, this year's new fashions, the flood's consequences, the war's ancient origins, the cathedral's spire_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Are you aware of ways to discriminate between contexts when this "extension" is possible and when it's not?

Comment: There has, for non-human 'possessors',  to be a verbalised 'belonging to' (eg 'part of', 'contingent on') rather than a mere general  'associated with' relation. Not _ We've found a bag. The bag's child must be near here._ ('owner' works.)  But this would be true for 'the stash's jewellery', which isn't natural-sounding.  But then _in nine days' time_ seems a counterexample. It might boil down to what we're used to hearing rather than a general semanto-syntactic rule.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There is that criterion to be got from CGEL, 5.118 (OTHER 'NOUNS OF SPECIAL RELEVANCE TO HUMAN ACTIVITY' ( duty's call (whereas usual: call of duty, the novel's structure, etc.)) but it is so general that I couldn't find it helpful in its application. This "might boil down to what we're used to hearing" is however a revelation. I'm afraid that this confirms the situation as the morass I suspected it to be.

Comment: Thanks very much for your replies, that's helped my understanding of apostrophe usage.